# anchor tag being applied only once in a while loop

Tags: php

I've been trying to set up a website wherein if the user goes to the specific page of my website the user will be able to see the messages that corresponds to the users email and the user will be able to click the whole table to view the whole message itself, but the anchor tag wraps itself only once in the entire while loop so i get a series of tables that only has one table that's clickable what should i do to wrap every table inside the anchor tag every while loop?

I've tried setting the anchor tag on every individual table row but the same thing still happens it's only being applied in the first table

```
$sql = "SELECT user_email, username, departmentSent, subject, report FROM userissues";
$result = $conn->query($sql);


if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

            if($row["departmentSent"] ==    $useremail=$_SESSION['user_email']){
                echo '<a href="#">
                <table border="1" style="margin-left: 162px; width: 300px; float: left; height: 50px;">
                <tr><td>'.$row["user_email"].'</td></tr><br>
                <tr><td>'.$row["subject"].'</td></tr><br>
                <tr><td> '.$row["report"].'</td></tr><br><br></a>';

            }else{
                echo'<p style="margin-left: 162px; width: 300px; float: left; height: 50px;" >there are no email that correspond to this email</p>';
                break;
            }
    }
    echo "</table>";
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
$conn->close();
?>
```

I want the user to actually  be able to click every table that's printed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should close the `</table>` before the close anchor tag `</a>`.

remove this line after while loop ends `echo </table>`;

add `</table>` before `</a>`

like this: `<tr><td> '.$row["report"].'</td></tr><br><br></table></a>`

it's because of DOM auto adjustment, where are you making multiple tables starting but closing them once so it removes the anchor and put them on end of a table to auto adjust.

hope this makes it working.

Comment: It's also an invalid code when you put __block__ element `<table>` into __inline__ element `<a>`.

Comment: Yes, better solutions could be
either use div inside the anchor element OR 
use anchor tag inside the `<tr>` OR `<td>` tags.
but still closing the `</table>` after loop can cause breaking the DOM.